# How to extract keys into type from object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a interface and type setup like that. Problem is that RawresourceId is `string | number` but i want it to be the actual keys of rawResources like `"ironOre" | "copperOre"...`. Can this be done somehow?

```
export interface Item {
    name: string;
}

export type ItemCollection = {[k:string]: Item};

export const rawResources: ItemCollection = {
    ironOre: {
        name: "Iron Ore",
    },
    copperOre: {
        name: "Copper Ore",
    },
    wood: {
        name: "Wood",
    },
    water: {
        name: "Water",
    }
} as const;

export type RawResourceId = keyof typeof rawResources;
```

Comment: It will work as intended if you don't specify the `ItemCollection` type for the `rawResources` object

Comment: But what if i want to limit the key: value to be only string: Item and nothing else. But also to get all te keys?

Comment: I don't think that you can both limit the key and have the `ItemCollection` type defined as it is. Since `ItemCollection` doesn't limit the keys, everything else works as intended. You'd have to predefine the keys in some way first, which is possible if you aren't constructing the `rawResources` object dynamically.

Comment: You can use the `satisfies` operator to do this; but since I don't have react expertise I won't post an answer; if you can [edit] to remove the dependency of the question on react by replacing with built in types, and also make sure you've presented a [mre] without references to undeclared/third-party/private things (e.g., `ItemType`, `Water`, etc, should be defined or replaced) then I could help further.

Comment: @jcalz seems like satisfies operator is what i needed :D

Comment: Then maybe you could write up your own answer with an explanation?  Or you could do the edit I suggested and then I might be able to.

Comment: @jcalz i removed the react part and made it simpler. Should be pure typescript now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable like `rawResources` with a type like `ItemCollection` which has only a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), then that's all the compiler knows about that variable. Since `keyof ItemCollection` is `string | number` then that's what you get for `keyof typeof rawResources` too, instead of the desired [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).

The right thing to do is simply not annotate and let the compiler infer the type of `rawResources` from the initializer.  But this won't check the value against `ItemCollection`, and presumably you want that, which is why you annotated the type in the first place.

Luckily you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to check the initializer against the `ItemCollection` type without *widening* it to that type and throwing away information you care about.  So you get that union of literal key types you wanted:

```
const rawResources = {
  ironOre: {
    name: "Iron Ore",
  },
  copperOre: {
    name: "Copper Ore",
  },
  wood: {
    name: "Wood",
  },
  water: {
    name: "Water",
  }
} as const satisfies ItemCollection;

type RawResourceId = keyof typeof rawResources;
// type RawResourceId = "ironOre" | "copperOre" | "wood" | "water"
```

and you still get type checking against `ItemCollection`:

```
const rawResources = {
  ironOre: {
    name: "Iron Ore",
  },
  copperOre: {
    name: "Copper Ore",
  },
  wood: {
    name: "Wood",
  },
  water: {
    title: "Water", // error! 
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '{ readonly title: "Water"; }' 
    //is not assignable to type 'Item'.
  }
} as const satisfies ItemCollection;
```

So it's the best of both worlds.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrrmAJ4AOK6EGAwgHsANsIgIwwQSGQBeHMgDaAa3JUaIWgF1yvLE0a4iJCp0QoA4oMEATHPmQJpVZFDgB3AEoQKggK5QSBRy9gQEwFDSAPJQZKFhBMZxAESokTIxEMkANA4ETLkJTpzcUJnkeAmJxClCJdDImTl5yAUt7tY2FS3VJOTJAOqdzQltCe5wkFDdVYQ1-QOT0CNhLPnIcMFOIC4Uk8AUMMA+aJhCouKS0oYEHNzInh7evgFIqHbyyhDsgjDIdxBfq4nj5-IEfIwCAB6KH-LgoR5eUGvCDvELJCLRWLJZAAH2QyWKpSaeIJHVsOPxyQmU2SzCMNVM5mQACE4HY8A5ti43EiXuDgvJKmFMSByvEEkl+mlpI1sYVVgqCEToOLhZL5gS6qU5Vkla19eSuhKwlKCUMKfqxmEadAZlVJGAxAsllAcsgYchoJEoABCZA9D1QgB+obD4dDyAAPABaGPIAAq8OQAHJsK4IOzpMJ2P9gE6UotafRWimA7MYQdCIIwBsKBRgLQiAAjMT-QRw+4pvQpgB0LTWrTrjmctb2kkOx2CenOYgkUhAN07CJB-LeH2QXx+fwBQN5zzBQUhQeXD1Xh9RG4x6RJVJVZWxpOpwyftrdrCYQA)